# Trying to make a sphere with triangle strips on OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, geometry

I'm trying to make an sphere with the OpenGl primitive GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP from OpenGL but it seems I'm missing something. The program starts from the botton of the sphere and from there it goes upwards.

Both divO and divA are the number of subdivions that the sphere has both verticaly and horizontaly.

Here is the code I tried.

```
void hacerEsfera (float radio, int divO, int divA) {

    float px, py,pz;
    int i,j;
    float incO = 2*M_PI / divO;
    float incA = M_PI /divA;

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP);
    glColor3i(1,0,0);

    //Depende del polo en el que empezemos
    for (i= 0 ; i<= divO; i++){
        for (j = 0; j<=divA ; j++) {


            if (i % 2 == 0){

            pz = cos (M_PI-(incA*j))*radio;
            py = sin (M_PI-(incA*j))*sin (incO*i)*radio;
            px = sin (M_PI-(incA*j))*cos (incO*i)*radio;

            glVertex3f (px, py, pz);

            pz = cos (M_PI-(incA*j))*radio;
            py = sin (M_PI-(incA*j))*sin (incO*(i+1))*radio;
            px = sin (M_PI-(incA*j))*cos (incO*(i+1))*radio;

            glVertex3f (px, py, pz);
           }

        else {
            pz = cos (incA*j)*radio;
            py = sin (M_PI-(incA*j))*sin (incO*i)*radio;
            px = sin (M_PI-(incA*j))*cos (incO*i)*radio;

            glVertex3f (px, py, pz);

            pz = cos (incA*j)*radio;
            py = sin (incA*j)*sin (incO*(i+1))*radio;
            px = sin (incA*j)*cos (incO*(i+1))*radio;

            glVertex3f (px, py, pz);
               }
    }
}
glEnd();
glFlush();
```

}

**EDIT** The sphere now shows but only either on the even or odd iterations can't tell which but I guess the odds ones.

[image]

**EDIT2** There's no need to make a diferent iteration for odd and even iterations removing it solved the problem, now the sphere looks fine.

Comment: You are calling `glBegin` multiple times before calling `glEnd` which results in a `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` error.

Comment: Tried what you said and now the sphere shows up but with some errors. Will post a picture on the main message.

Comment: `glColor3i` strikes me as a bit unusual. A constant value of **1** in a call to `glColor3i` is nearly black because the range is [-2^31 - 2^31-1]. Maybe you meant `glColor3f`?

Comment: Yes I meant to glColor3f.

Comment: Feel free to post the solution you found as an answer to your own question. Doing so is in fact encouraged, and definitely preferred over an edit which includes the answer in the text of the question itself.

Comment: see [here](https://github.com/AzamatEm/Android-OpenGLVR/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/iamoem/openglvr/SphereVideoRenderer.java) for a solution